# extend liferay plugin functionality with hooks

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6

Fairly new to Liferay. I learned it is possible to create plugins UI with different frameworks including JSF. Also I learned I can extend functionality of an existing plugin with hooks.  Now I am curious if it is possible to add new JSF pages to an existing plugin which interface is build with JSP using hooks?

Suppose I want to extend dynamic data list portlet, add some new functionality and for this I need to add new pages.

- Is it possible to add new pages in general?
- Can I create a new plugin with JSF as a front end framework, implement the logic I want to add within JSF pages, would it be possible to redirect a user from an original JSP to those JSF pages, let user do something there and then return the user back to original dynamic_data_list JPSs?
- If it is possible, how can I do this with Liferay 6.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The mechanics are documented in the [developer guide](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en) or the [Wiki](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugin+to+extend+a+plugin). It's not exactly a hook that you deploy to the running system, rather a development option to inject custom changes into existing plugins, and you deploy the modified version instead of the original one.

With this, you can do everything that you can add as extra feature this way (see the build process). Technically the answer to the first two bulletpoints is "yes". If the linked documentation doesn't help answering your third bulletpoint, please ask more specifically what actually doesn't work. But keep in mind that only core liferay is customizable with hooks, plugins are customizable at compile time - and not with hooks.